# Run both test without closing

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This are my two test methods:

```
[Test]
public void Test00NewCustomerRegistrationPrePaidHo()
{
    HomePage homePage = new HomePage(driver, Reporter);
    homePage.ExpandMenu("Registration")
            .SelectMenuItem("Customer Application");
    applicationnumber = RandomString(RandomStringType.Numeric, 10);

    NewCustomerRegistrationPagePrePaidHo newCustomerRegistrationPagePrePaidHo = new NewCustomerRegistrationPagePrePaidHo(driver, Reporter);
    newCustomerRegistrationPagePrePaidHo.ClickNewCustomerApplicationData()
                                 .ValidateApplicationNumber(applicationnumber)
                                 .EnterEntityName("Automation")
                                 .EnterCustomerName(RandomString(RandomStringType.Alpha, 10),
                                                  RandomString(RandomStringType.Alpha, 10),
                                                  RandomString(RandomStringType.Alpha, 10))
                                 .EnterOtherCustomerDetails("", "", dHandler.GetAppData(TcfaDataKeys.DATEOFBIRTH), RandomString(RandomStringType.Alpha, 5) +
                                                        RandomString(RandomStringType.Numeric, 4) +
                                                        RandomString(RandomStringType.Alpha, 1))
                                 .EnterAddressInfo(dHandler.GetAppData(TcfaDataKeys.COUNTRY),
                                                 dHandler.GetAppData(TcfaDataKeys.STATE),
                                                 dHandler.GetAppData(TcfaDataKeys.DISTRICT),
                                                 dHandler.GetAppData(TcfaDataKeys.CITY))
                               .EnterContactInformation(RandomString(RandomStringType.Numeric, 2),
                                                        RandomString(RandomStringType.Numeric, 10),
                                                        RandomString(RandomStringType.Numeric, 10))

                               .EnterAccountInformation(dHandler.GetAppData(TcfaDataKeys.BANKACTYPE),
                                                         dHandler.GetAppData(TcfaDataKeys.NAMEOFBANK))
                               .SubmitNewCustomerInformation();
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}

[Test]
public void Test01PendingCustomerRegistrationPrePaidHo()
{
    String number = applicationnumber;
    HomePage homePage = new HomePage(driver, Reporter);
    homePage.ExpandMenu("Registration")
            .SelectMenuItem("Customer Registration");

    PendingCustomerRegistrationHo pendingCustomerRegistrationHo = new PendingCustomerRegistrationHo(driver, Reporter);
    pendingCustomerRegistrationHo.ClickListofPendingcustomerApplication()
                                 .ClickPending(number)
                                 .ClickSaveAndNext()
                                 .ClickSaveAndNext()
                                 .EnterCardEnrollmentInformation("1", "2")
                                 .ClickSaveAndNext()
                                 .ClickSaveAndNext()
                                 .ClickSaveAndNext()
                                 .AddVehicleDetails(2)
                                 .ClickSaveAndNext()
                                 .EnterEnrollementDetails(RandomString(RandomStringType.Alpha, 10))
                                 .EnterDispatchDetails("000001 RCPHO TCOPS");

    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

There is a tear down method at the end of the final test.

Every time I run my scripts, the test execute, closes the browser, re-open the browser again and runs the second test.

I want a test where I can run these scripts without closing the browser.

Comment: Which test automation framework you are using ?

Comment: Using Page object model. The reference added in Visual studio is Nunit framework

Comment: Does Nunit support Annotations like TestNG. I can solve this issue in TestNG.

Comment: I am not sure on this..

Comment: Yes They are attributes in Nunit. I've found a way for your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your issue. I've mapped TestNG with Nunit . And have written code for Nunit:

```
[SetUpFixture]
    public void setUpClass(){
        // Marks a class with one-time setup or teardown methods for all the test fixtures in a namespace.
        // instantiate your driver object here // 
    }

[SetUp]
    public void setUpMethod(){
        // Indicates a method of a TestFixture called just before each test method.
        // your login or before method activity(which would be running before every test method)
    }

[Test]
    public void testMethod1(){
        // Marks a method of a TestFixture that represents a test.
        // Your Test Method.
    }

[Test]
    public void testMethod2(){
        // Marks a method of a TestFixture that represents a test.
        // Your Test Method.
    }

[TearDown]
    public void tearDownMethod(){
         // Indicates a method of a TestFixture called just after each test method.
         // your log out or after method activity(which would be running after every test method) 
    }

}
```

For more reference you can follow this link : https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Attributes

Please let me know if you have any concerns related to this.

Comment: Frankly, I haven't understood the use of setup fixture method. I have already added "[TestFixtureSource(typeof(BrowserSource), "Browsers")]" in the beginning of my script after namespace.

Comment: SetUpFixture would be invoked only once in a class whereas SetUp would be invoked before running every Test method.

Comment: Initialize your browser instance in SetUpFixture.